# get transaction amount values using Besu and webj in java

Tags: java, web3-java, hyperledger-besu

Im trying to get transaction amount of Besu transaction using web3j and java. Unfortunately without success. Input allways return 0x. Can anyone tell me what to change?

```
        String transactionHash = "0xe7df62446f91106dea2cca0d9cdb2655cd15738d6cdad00f5bb5327fd35648dd";
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService(Vars.nodeUrl));
        EthGetTransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(transactionHash).send();
        System.out.println("Transaction receipt: " + transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().get());

        List<Log> logs = transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().get().getLogs();

        System.out.println("Log size: "+logs.size());

        String inputdata;
        Optional<Transaction> tx = web3j.ethGetTransactionByHash(transactionHash).send().getTransaction();
        if (tx.isPresent()) {
            inputdata = tx.get().getInput();
            System.out.println("Input data: "+inputdata);
        }

        Optional<TransactionReceipt> transReceipt = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt(transactionHash).send().getTransactionReceipt();
```